# How to change background colour of opened bootstrap dropdown list - Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, toggle, navbar, dropdown

How to change background colour of opened bootstrap dropdown option. Here is the code:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-inverse bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar6">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Title </a>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse justify-content-stretch" id="navbar6">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About<span class="sr-only">Home</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Services
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Design</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Development</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Consulting</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

In bootstrap 3 I changed it with the help of:

```css
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover {
  background: #080808;
}
```

It was a standard code of bootstrap 3 (not work in bootstrap4) 
how do I do the same thing only in bootstrap 4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```css
.navbar .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #BADA55;
}

/* and this styles the dropdwon trigger link, when open */
.navbar .dropdown.show a { 
  background-color: #BADA55;
}
```

...is enough.

Note `.navbar` limits it to menu and without it, it would style all `.dropdown`s, as long as you load your `CSS` after `bootstrap(.min).css`.

```css
.navbar .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #BADA55;
}
.navbar .dropdown.show a {
  background-color: #BADA55;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-stretch" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
       <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Services
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Design</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Development</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Consulting</a>
    </div>
  </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Please note none of your current selectors match anything, since you don't seem to have applied `navbar-default` class to any element.

As a general rule, expect ***many*** class names to have been refactored in v4, which allows shorter, more expressive syntax and greater overall flexibility.
Applying v3 solutions to v4 examples is generally regarded as bad practice, just like expecting v2 solutions to work on v3 examples.

Comment: I need to at the opening `class = "nav-item dropdown"` changed the color of the element `dropdown-toggle`. [Now](https://i.imgur.com/zUMaDVN.png), [it was in bootstrap3](https://i.imgur.com/yoOfCLI.png) See?

Comment: @PavelFedorov While a few regular expressions are really helpful for crossing page contents over from Bootstrap v3 to v4, the navigation is always done faster if you do it from scratch and start from the v4 navigation examples. I have come to this conclusion after crossing quite a few small websites/templates from Bootstrap v3 to v4 and other people at my work place have come to the same conclusion. Besides, the code you provided is not valid Bootstrap v4 navigation markup. After you fix it, the code I provided will work, as you can see it is working in my example (valid v4 markup).

Comment: On another note, you should keep in mind Bootstrap (any version) is nothing more than a collection of `CSS` (and sometimes `JS`) snippets. Regardless of version you are allowed (and sometimes even required) to apply changes to it in order to achieve certain particular results. You should not expect selectors containing classes you do not use in your markup to match anything in your page. That's basic `CSS`, has nothing to do with any version of Bootstrap.

Comment: I just need to change the background of the main element when disclosed submenu. As I have shown in the screenshots in the comment above. I don't know how to do that. I'm not good at JS and I not fully understand how to work selectors type .open .

Comment: @PavelFedorov 1. Did you look at the example in my answer? Does it do what you want? Click on (Show code snippet to see it). 2. Can you create a [mcve] with your current code?

Comment: Yes, I saw your example, but that's not what I need. See [Bootstrap3](http://codepen.io/mr_aleks/pen/YZWgYw) and there [Bootstrap4](http://codepen.io/mr_aleks/pen/KWMEoe)

Comment: It's not working because you need to include `tether.min.js` before `bootstrap.min.js`. Look into the console. Compare with my example, where I include it.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot to plug it in. But your code changes the background drop-down submenus, but I need to, when you open a sub-menu that changed the header background "Services"

Comment: Thank you very much, I was approached by your option but without the "a" `.navbar .dropdown.show`, as if a "a" that changes the background and drop-down menu too. I have not yet experienced enough, and for me such as the selectors `.show` and `.open` new to me. Where can I read about them?

Comment: `.navbar .dropdown.show a` applies to any `<a>` that is a descendant of an element with classes `dropdown` and `show`, that is a descendant of an element with the class `navbar`. I didn't know v4 appies `show` instead of `open` before this, but I inspected and noticed it. I composed the selector above, which works. You don't need to learn them, you just need to learn how to find them. That is to inspect. You need [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) + [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp).

Answer (score 1):

This works for Bootstrap 4.1.3:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: good but better have the rule more specific to navbar as in the accepted answer.